# Button color change

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color on my submit button but not the words. There is no button-color option in css. This is for my personal about me page for coding camp. Having trouble finding answers. Here is my code.

```css
#sub{
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="summer">
        <label for="vehicle1"> I like summer.</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="phone">
        <label for="vehicle2"> I have a phone.</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="bugs">
        <label for="vehicle3"> I dont like bugs.</label><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"id="sub">
      </form>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. which color you wish to change? the text color or the background color? because this "I want to change the color on my submit button but not the words" doesn't make sense that you want to change the color but not the words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't set the color of the button. You would set the color of three different aspects of the button.

1. Set the color of the button's text

   color: red;
2. Set the color of the button's background

   background-color: red;
3. Set the color of the button's border

   border: 1px solid red;

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you set background-color. And for the text color inside the button you put color.

```
#sub{
    background-color: black;
    color: gold;
}
```

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="summer">
        <label for="vehicle1"> I like summer.</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="phone">
        <label for="vehicle2"> I have a phone.</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="bugs">
        <label for="vehicle3"> I dont like bugs.</label><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"id="sub">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may change it with `background-color` property.

```css
#sub {
  color: black;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="summer">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I like summer.</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="phone">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a phone.</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="bugs">
  <label for="vehicle3"> I dont like bugs.</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```css
#sub{
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with background-color property

```
#sub {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sub {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .2em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

(I added some other stuff in there to make it look nice.)